# Can't get AJAX request to return data from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a page with a list, with a number of checkboxes. When I check the boxes and click submit, I want an AJAX request to take the value of the checkboxes, stick them into an array, send that array to my 'setCourses' method, where I will use the array values to pull data out of the DB and then send that data back to the page as JSON. This is my first time trying AJAX so sorry for any silly mistakes!

The AJAX request seems to work, sending the array to the controller method, but I can't get the success function to return the data I want to send back from the controller. Here is what I have so far:

**setCourses Method**

```
    public function setCourses(Request $request) {

    $courses = $request->get('selectedCourses');

    //Here I will use the "$selectedCourses" array above to query the database for specific info,
    //but for now I am just trying to get the AJAX to return anything!

    return response::json($courses);

}
```

**AJAX to get checkbox values, add to array and send request**

```
    $('.submitCourses').on('click', function(){

    var selectedCourses = $("input:checkbox[name=courseID]:checked").map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    console.log(selectedCourses);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'report-generator/custom/selected',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { selectedCourses: selectedCourses },

        success:function(courses){

          console.log(courses);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: please try to change `return` to `echo` in php function

Answer (score 0):

try this one

> to change use helper function instead of facade

`return response()->json($courses);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = { selectedCourses: selectedCourses };

$.get('/eport-generator/custom/selected', obj,
  function (response) { console.log(response);}
).fail(function () {
   console.log("error");
});
```